# Efficiently sample a data frame avoiding loops

Tags: performance, r, loops, sampling

I have a data frame which consists of a first column (experiment.id) and the rest of the columns are values associated with this experiment id. Each row is a unique experiment id. My data frame has columns in the order of 10⁴ - 10⁵.

```
data.frame(experiment.id=1:100, v1=rnorm(100,1,2),v2=rnorm(100,-1,2) )
```

This data frame is the source of my sample space. What i would like to do, is for each unique experiment.id (row) randomly sample (with replacement) one of the values v1, v2, ....,v10000 associated with this id and construct a sample s1. In each sample s1 all experiment ids are represented.

Eventually i want to perform 10⁴ samples, s1, s2, ....,s 10⁴ and calculate some statistic.

What would be the most efficient way (computationally) to perform this sampling process. I would like to avoid for loops as much as possible.

**Update:**
My questions in not all about sampling but also storing the samples. I guess my real question is if there is a quicker way to perform the above other than

```
d<-data.frame(experiment.id=1:1000, replicate (10000,rnorm(1000,100,2)) )
results<-data.frame(d$experiment.id,replicate(n=10000,apply(d[,2:10001],1,function(x){sample(x,size=1,replace=T)})))
```

Comment: experiment.id is any unique character string / number

Comment: `replicate` and `apply` are essentially looping and slow. Any of the answers posted so far will be faster if you have the capacity to store such a matrix.  If space does become an issue then you'll need to loop over the rows and get your statistics out of them as you go.  So, figure that part out in advance.  So far you've implied that you need 1e9 values.  That's getting into a multi-gigabyte matrix.

Comment: @John Thanks for you input. My primary problem, as you mention, is computation time and storage not the sampling procedure per se. Calculating the statistics "on-the-fly" would an option but it would come handy to have the complete dataset beforehand and do the analyses post hoc. Thanks your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest and most readable IMHO is still to use `apply`, but making good use of the fact that `sample` is vectorized:

```
results <- data.frame(experiment.id = d$experiment.id,
                      t(apply(d[, -1], 1, sample, 10000, replace = TRUE)))
```

If the 3 seconds it takes are too slow for your needs then I would recommend you use matrix indexing.

Comment: Can this be correct? You sample each row and return a vector. How is this vector entered in the result dataframe?

Comment: The speed of this will depend a lot on the number of rows

Comment: @ECII, `t(apply(...))` will return a 1000-by-10000 matrix that will be binded to the experiment ids by `data.frame`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an expression that chooses one of the columns (excluding the first).  It does not copy the first column, you will need to supply that as a separate step.

For a data frame `d`:

```
d[matrix(c(seq(nrow(d)), sample(ncol(d)-1, nrow(d), replace=TRUE)+1), ncol=2)]
```

That's one sample.  To get `N` samples, just multiply the selection (as in John's answer):

```
mm <- matrix(c(rep(seq(nrow(d)), N), sample(ncol(d)-1, nrow(d)*N, replace=TRUE)+1), ncol=2)

result <- matrix(d[mm], ncol=N)
```

But you're going to have memory issues.

Comment: Thanks. Your first line constructs a sample. I would like however to construct *and store* 10⁴ of those samples and afterwards perform some statistics. What would be an efficient to create and store this large amount of samples?

Comment: @ECII Save it to a variable?  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Save all samples to a data frame for further statistical analyses. See my the update of my question and Johns comment

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do without any looping whatsoever.  If you convert your columns after the first one to a matrix this gets easy because a matrix can be addressed either as [row, column] or sequentially as it's underlying vector.

```
mat <- as.matrix(datf[,-1])
nr <- nrow(mat); nc <- ncol(mat)
sel <- sample( 1:nc, nr, replace = TRUE )
sel <- sel + ((1:nr)-1) * nc
x <- t(mat)[sel]
seldatf <- data.frame( datf[,1], x = x )
```

Now, to get lots of the samples it pretty easy just multiplying the same logic.

```
ns <- 10 # number of samples / row
sel <- sample(1:nc, nr * ns, replace = TRUE )
sel <- sel + rep(((1:nr)-1) * nc, each = ns)
x <- t(mat)[sel]
seldatf <- cbind( datf[,1],  data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = ns, byrow = TRUE)) )
```

It's possible that it's going to be a really big data frame if you're going to set `ns <- 1e5` and you have lots of rows.  You may have to watch running out of memory. I do a bit of unnecessary copying for readability reasons.  You can eliminate that for memory, and speed because once you are using large amounts of memory you'll be swapping out other programs that are running.  That is slow.  You don't have to assign and save x, mat, or even sel.  The result of not doing that would provide you about the fastest answer possible.